# Emulator for iPhone, iPad, and Mobile Browser

Tags: iphone, ipad, emulation

I'm building website for mobile,
and I want to running the application in the mobile browser, iPhone, and iPad.
Is there any download link for the emulator?
I prefer a free application.

Comment: It's frustrating that many people think "emulator" and "simulator" mean the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run your app in mobile browsers in the iOS Simulator on the Mac, which can simulate both iPhone and iPad.

If you are on a Mac, use Spotlight (command-space) to search for "iOS".  It should come up if it's installed.

If it is not installed, install [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) and it should be installed with it.

If you are not on a Mac, there is no official emulator or simulator.  There may be unofficial ones, but they probably won't be free, if they exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

to run iPhone emulator you will need a mac (it's only available on macOS). Install xCode (http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php)

end run simulator. it's free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac then use XCode. If you are stuck on Windows try iPhone Drift http://www.aviassin.com/iphonedrift or Electric Plum http://www.electricplum.com/simulator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to quickly view how a webpage would render at various mobile device resolutions then `synthphone.com` is a nice little webpage.

**NOTE: synthphone is NOT an emulator!  this website only lets you simulate browsers of various widths and heights!**

http://synthphone.com

you can even link directly to a url via query strings. for example, click the link below which points to the Sencha Touch 2 carousel.

http://www.synthphone.com/?u=http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/carousel/index.html

(Use your mouse like a finger to slide around the images etc.)

enjoy!

Comment: Synthphone is a browser simulator (not an emulator).

Comment: good point - updated the comment to be more clear in this fact